# Относительные пути в golang

Tags: golang, маршрутизация, config

Есть такое дерево:

```
|-cmd 
|   |-task
|       |-main.go
|
|-configs
|    |-config.yaml
|
|-pkg
    |-runner
         |-runner.go
         |-runner_test.go
```

В `runner.go` к `config.yaml` обращаюсь так: `../../configs/`. И тесты `runner_test.go` проходят. Однако после билда создается бинарник в корне проекта, который после запуска выдает ошибку обращения к конфигу, потому что уходит на две директории назад от корня проекта. И если изменить обращение к конфигу в `runner.go` на `./configs/`, тогда после билда всё успешно запустится, однако при тестировании возникнет ошибка обращения к конфигу.
Как правильно обращаться к конфигу?

Comment: а вы viper используйте для конфига?

Answer (score 0):

ответ зависит от того, что вы используйте для чтения конфига.

одни из попульярных инструментов - это а .
На нем вы можете указать несколько путей к конфигу: как для тестов, так и для main app.

```
v := viper.New()
v.SetConfigName("config")
v.SetConfigType("yaml")
v.AddConfigPath(".")
v.AddConfigPath("./configs")
```

тогда у вас конфиг будет искаться как в текущей директории, так и в ./configs

p.s. лучше иметь возможность передать пусть к конфигу.

Answer (score -1):

1. Напишите вывод терминала. Не надо заставлять отвечающих догадываться что именно выводит компилятор.
2. Если вы используете `pkg`, тогда необходимо использовать и `internal` (чисто логически).
3. Как вы запускаете ваши тесты?